# How to make Div expand width with 100%

Tags: html, css

I had make a container and make it to the middle width margin: 0 auto, but I had face a problem is I would like to make the some content width is fit to the window width with 100% width?

Any way to make it?

If i using padding:0 400px and margn-left:-200 ?

**here is my working code.**

**CSS**

```
html, body {width:100%; height:100%; background:lightblue}
* { margin:0; padding:0}
#container { 
  width:1024px;
  min-height:100%;
  background:red;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
 }

header {
   width:100%;
  height:80px;
  background:skyblue;
}

header ul {list-style-type:none; float:right}
header ul li {display:inline-block; padding: 10px; 20px;}

#content {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:yellow;
  padding:0 300px;
  margin-left:-200px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/jaminpie/pen/CHrIf

Thansk for the help..

Answer (score 0):

For window width with 100% width

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/kougiland/pen/Gmufd)

use [1/100th of the width of the viewport.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)

```
  width:100vw;
```

and [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

[image]

full code:

```
* { box-sizing:border-box;margin:0; padding:0}

html, body {width:100vw; height:100vh; background:lightblue}

#container { 
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;

  background:red;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
 }

header {
   width:100%;
  height:80px;
  background:skyblue;
}

header ul {list-style-type:none; float:right}
header ul li {display:inline-block; padding: 10px; 20px;}

#content {
  width:100vw;
  height:200px;
  background:yellow;
  padding:0 300px;
  margin-left:-200px;
}
```

Comment: but this still need the margin-left: -200px right ??

Comment: no you don't need it if your plan is to show the full div it was there before

Answer (score 0):

Move the content div outside of the container, then give it absolute positioning 80px from the top so that it falls right below the header.

```
#content {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:yellow;
  padding:0 300px;
  position:absolute;
  top:80px;
}
```

## [Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CFysh)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help and code, but what if I have a sticky footer. If I using absolute the footer wont help me to push to bottom?

Comment: Just do `position:absolute;` and `bottom:0;` on the footer.